# which is best practice? Redundant loop, or calling the same if statements?

Tags: python, optimization, redundancy

I'm in the process of learning how to write the most optimal and readable code. The first way I wrote this has redundant for-loops but only checks eviction policy once. While my second way doesn't have redundant for loops but checks the eviction policy every iteration. Is there a better way to write this code?

```
    if self.remainingSpace - content.size < 0:
        if evictionPolicy == 'lru':
            while self.remainingSpace - content.size < 0:
                self.lruEvict()
        else:
            while self.remainingSpace - content.size < 0:
                self.mruEvict()
```

or

```
    if self.remainingSpace - content.size < 0:
        while self.remainingSpace - content.size < 0:
            if evictionPolicy == 'lru':
                self.lruEvict()
            else:
                self.mruEvict()
```

Comment: In both cases, you don't need the top-level if

Comment: It's almost always better in higher level languages to keep evaluations/decisions outside of loops. @ShadowRanger has the winner.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest and fastest version. Since `evictionPolicy` never changes, select the *method* up front, put it in a common name, then use a single common loop:

```
evict = self.lruEvict if evictionPolicy == 'lru' else self.mruEvict

while self.remainingSpace - content.size < 0:  # As noted on the other answer, self.remainingSpace < content.size would be slightly more efficient
    evict()
```

No doubling of code, no runtime repeated checks for which method to call on each loop.

Comment: I love your use of functionalism here.

Answer (score 1):

As @olivier-melançon mentioned, you don't need the first `if` statmement, since the `while` loop only enters in that case anyway.

The first version is more efficient, but if either `self.lruEvict()` or `self.mruEvict()` are expensive, then the efficiency savings may be negligible:

```py
    if evictionPolicy == 'lru':
        while self.remainingSpace < content.size:
            self.lruEvict()
    else:
        while self.remainingSpace < content.size:
            self.mruEvict()
```

The second is more readable IMO:

```py
    while self.remainingSpace < content.size:
        if evictionPolicy == 'lru':
            self.lruEvict()
        else:
            self.mruEvict()
```

Another option which would be the same efficiency as the second option, more concise, but perhaps a bit more obscure:

```py
    while self.remainingSpace < content.size:
        self.lruEvict() if evictionPolicy == 'lru' else self.mruEvict()
```

When you use the `thing_if_true if condition else thing_if_false` ternary operator in Python, the `thing_if_true` only gets calculated or run if `condition` is truthy, and `thing_if_false` only gets calculated or run if `condition` is falsey.

Edit: Removed the `-` operator by swapping `content.size` to the right side of the `<`, since if we're micro-optimizing, it uses unnecessary overhead, and moreover the code looks nicer w/o it.